# SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE staus == open/pending/closed/all

Tags: php, select

If user selected Display all Show open, pending and closed results.

If user selected Display pending Show pending results.

**Is it possible to make this work with one query?**

```
<?php

$status = isset($_GET['status']) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'status', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';// pending, closed, open, all //

if($status == 'pending' or $status == 'closed' or $status == 'open'){

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user = :user AND status = :status ORDER BY dateCreated DESC';
    $select = $db->prepare($query);
    $select->bindParam(':user', $userInfo['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $select->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $select->execute(); 

}else{

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user = :user ORDER BY dateCreated DESC';
    $select = $db->prepare($query);
    $select->bindParam(':user', $userInfo['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $select->execute(); 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the SQL string before preparing it.  If `$status` is what you want, then just add in that clause.  Then instead of using `bindParam`, you can just pass an array to `execute()`.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user = :user';
$params = array(
    'user' => $userInfo['username']
);

if(in_array($status, array('pending', 'closed', 'open'))){
    $query .= ' AND status = :status';
    $params['status'] = $status;
}

$query .= ' ORDER BY dateCreated DESC';

$select = $db->prepare($query);
$select->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$status = isset($_GET['status']) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'status', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';// pending, closed, open, all //
if($status == 'pending' or $status == 'closed' or $status == 'open')
    $stquery='AND status = :status';
else
    $stquery = '';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user = :user '.$status.' ORDER BY dateCreated DESC';
    $select = $db->prepare($query);
    $select->bindParam(':user', $userInfo['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

if(!empty($stquery)
    $select->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$select->execute();
```